# What is the best approach to add CSS with Javascript targeting a specific aria-label?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter, tampermonkey

I want to add a CSS property to a tag with a specific aria-label, when the document loads I want to change a section flex order to 2

I want to use javascript to target the aria-label 'block 1' so I can change the order with flex using 'order: 2'

```html
<section aria-label="block 1">
BLOCK 1
</section>
<section aria-label="block 2">
BLOCK 2
</section>
```

I tried this but I was a long shot

```js
var element = document.querySelector('[aria-label="Section navigation"]').addGlobalStyle(".flexorder { order: 2; }");
})();
```

I want that the section with aria-label="block 2" display first than aria-label="block 1" but I can only use javascript

Answer (score 0):

*You want to know how to change the order of two elements. If you ask it that way, you'll probably get an answer faster.*

To your question: To add a CSS property use the command specific made for this: [`GM_addStyle();`](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#GM_addStyle)

Example:

```
GM_addStyle("section[aria-label="block 1"]{order:2}");
GM_addStyle("section[aria-label="block 2"]{order:1}");
```

You also need to get the `div` surrounding those two or add a div surrounding them and add `display: flex;` as style.